# Why does AWS Lambda concatenate slots of type AMAZON.NUMBER when added?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am learning Alexa & AWS Lambda and am trying to determine why, when a slot of type AMAZON.NUMBER is added to another number (an attribute, in my case) the numbers go directly together as if they are being concatenated rather than added?

```
'CountSeveralTimes': function(){
  var count = this.event.request.intent.slots.count.value;
  this.attributes['currentCount'] = this.attributes['currentCount'] + count;
  this.response.speak("Nice Job! You have now counted " + 
  this.attributes['currentCount']+ " times.").listen();
  this.emit(':responseReady');
},
```

Say I ran the above piece of code, with the value of "count", which is of slot type AMAZON.NUMBER, being 10, and a currentCount of 10. Rather than adding 10 + 10 to evaluate to 20, it instead returns "Nice Job! You have now counted 1010 times." I tried to debug by putting a random number in between their addition to see which one was adding improperly. The attribute (currentCount), adds properly, but anything the count variable from the slot does not.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a JavaScript issue. `this.event.request.intent.slots.count.value` is of type `string` instead of `number` as you might think.
That means, that the expression `this.attributes['currentCount'] + count` has **not** the form `number + number` which would cause the plus sign to act as the arithmetical addition operator, which is what you want.

To fix this, explicitly type-cast the operands:

```
 this.attributes['currentCount'] = Number( this.attributes['currentCount'] ) +
 Number( count );
```

Comment: If you are sure, that `this.attributes['currentCount']` is always of type `number`, you can omit the first `Number()`